# Log4j2 HTMLLayout Configuration and Output

Tags: java, swing, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to include Log4J in my Swing application and things gets confused when I have Log4J 1.x tutorials every time I am trying to search rather than Log4J2, I believe not much might have changed but in between all this I am not getting an HTML log file as output as I had expected with below setup.

I am following below instructions from [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j/how-to-create-logs-in-html-format-using-log4j/):

**Properties File:**

```
# log4j2.properties
# Define the root logger with file appender
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, HTML

log4j.appender.HTML=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.HTML.File=app_${current.date.time}.log

# Define the html layout for file appender
log4j.appender.HTML.layout=org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout
log4j.appender.HTML.layout.Title=App Log
log4j.appender.HTML.layout.LocationInfo=true
log4j.appender.HTML.Threshold=DEBUG
```

**Initialization:**

```
// Static block to create new System Property that help us creating new Log time every run
    static{

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyyhhmmss");
        System.setProperty("current.date.time", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    }
// Initiate Logger instance
private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(MainWindow.class);
```

**Writing Log:**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        // Log
        LOGGER.debug("Application Initializing");
//...Other code follows for JFrame and components initialization
```

I am in impression that even after just one line Logging I should be getting a Log file generated, but it is not.
What am I doing wrong here?

I tried searching for `.properties` file changes in 2.10 version on Apache's [website](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties) but did not get any doubts cleared.

I am using NetBeans 8.2 if needed to know.

- Asif

Comment: show us how do you initialize the LOGGER

Comment: @HaimRaman thanks for pointing out, updated my question :)

Comment: What about log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, HTML

Comment: My bad, it is there in program already, forgot to copy from top. .

Comment: Can you add the pom.xml

Comment: Umm.. pom.xml? I do not have that, do we need pom.xml in a Swing app?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163596/discussion-between-haim-raman-and-asif).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the old (1.2.7) log4j.properites file in your example.

Use this link 
https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j2/log4j2-htmllayout-configuration-example/

It includes a log4j2.properies file as well (copied it below from the blog)

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig

#Make sure to change log file path as per your need
property.filename = C:\\logs\\app-info.html

filters = threshold

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug

appenders = rolling

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = debug-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.html.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = HTMLLayout
appender.rolling.layout.charset = UTF-8
appender.rolling.layout.title = Howtodoinjava Info Logs
appender.rolling.layout.locationInfo = true
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 20

loggers = rolling

#Make sure to change the package structure as per your application
logger.rolling.name = com.howtodoinjava
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked, only thing that's left is the trick `${current.date.time}` I was using to generate new log file for every run, Let me know if you find something for that. .else I can live with what we got :)